# Go net/http Transport Accept-Encoding: gzip not prompting encoded response

Tags: http, go

Possibly related to [Go: Detect gzip encoding to manually decompress response, but 'Content-Encoding' header missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064556/go-detect-gzip-encoding-to-manually-decompress-response-but-content-encoding)

I understand that net/http Transport will add `Accept-Encoding: gzip` to a request unless `DisableCompression` is set to True, and that is required if I want it to automatically decompress a gzipped response. That being the case, the following code does not receive a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header:
https://play.golang.org/p/FWs5uG9pZEL (note: will not run in the playground due to network constraints)

If I run a local server and run the above code with it I can see the expected header being sent:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5555
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Is there something else about the connection go creates that is causing the server not to return a gzipped response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Accept-Encoding: gzip` only means that the **client is able** and willing to handle gzip compressed content. **It does not mean that the server must actually compress the content**. In fact, for example with images it would not make any sense to compress the content with gzip because these are already compressed data (but not with gzip) and adding gzip on top might actually increase the size of the payload.

If you want your server to return compressed content you actually have to configure your server to do this. See for example [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/) on how to do this with nginx.

Note that `http.Response` will **transparently decompress** the response and **update the header** accordingly, i.e. remove `Content-Encoding`. This means **you will not get the original response header** when checking with `resp.Header.Get("Content-Encoding")`. If the response was automatically decompressed can be seen in the `Uncompressed` field:

```
fmt.Println("was compressed ", resp.Uncompressed)
```

For more see `go doc http.Response`:

```
// Uncompressed reports whether the response was sent compressed but
// was decompressed by the http package. When true, reading from
// Body yields the uncompressed content instead of the compressed
// content actually set from the server, ContentLength is set to -1,
// and the "Content-Length" and "Content-Encoding" fields are deleted
// from the responseHeader. To get the original response from
// the server, set Transport.DisableCompression to true.
Uncompressed bool
```

Comment: I understand and agree with what you have put but my code example includes a request to https://golang.org which is a platform that does return a gzipped response if the client provides ```Accept-Encoding: gzip``` in the request. My question refers to the issue that go _appears_ to be sending the correct header yet I don't get the gzipped response and header.

Comment: @jonhadfield: That `https://golang.org` will usually return compressed content is a detail I did no see in your question. I've updated the answer to add additional information, especially that go will automatically decompress the response and update the response header so you will not get the original `Content-Encoding` send by the server.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I incorrectly assumed the response was returned uncompressed due to the absence of the Content-Encoding header.